# using ng-show in directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to define a directive to show a checkmark when a question has been answered.

```js
questModule.directive('showCheckmarkOnDone', function () {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    template: "<div ng-transclude></div><img src='img/checkmark.svg' " +
        "ng-show='scope.questions[type][number-1].done' " + 
        "class='checkmark' style='height: {{height}}px; width: {{height}}px;'>",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.height = $(".app").height()/12;
      scope.number = attrs.number;
      scope.type = attrs.type;
    }
  };
});
```

The `scope.questions[type][number-1].done` exists in my controller for the page, and I can see that it is being updated correctly when I press the done button. However, the directive does not register the change.  I tried putting a $watch in the link function - that didn't help either.  I think I'm a bit confused about how to get my directive scope to play nicely with my controller scope - any thoughts on how I can give this directive access to an object that exists in an outside controller? (`scope.questions`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a valid way to define directive scope:

```
scope: '@'
```

You can either (a) not define it, (b) set it to `true`, or (c) set it to `{}` (an object).  See the docs for more info: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive (find the header: "Directive Definition Object")

In this case, I imagine if you remove it, you may be OK, because it will allow `scope.questions` to be visible from your directive.  If you reproduce the issue in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) or [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co), it would be much easier to assist you.

Edit:

1. Your directive generally should have 1 parent element
2. You should not use `scope` in your directive's HTML, it's implied
3. I think you said as much in your comment, but you should strive to make your directive more generic by passing in scope.questions[0][0].done instead of looking it up in your directive's HTML using attributes.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/EZy2F/1/

Comment: Thanks, but I removed it and nothing changed.  I thought doing that gave individual instances of the directive their own scope, as opposed to sharing a scope amongst all copies of the directive.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  You shouldn't be using `scope` your in template... it's implied: http://jsfiddle.net/EZy2F/1/

Comment: Thanks... I was also able to construct a working JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/nicolethenerd/3U5WF/) - unfortunately, I still don't know what's wrong w/ the code in my actual project.

Comment: How could I pass "scope.questions[0][0].done" into my directive?

Comment: If you can make it available, I'm happy to take a look.  Your fiddle is bound to `scope.done`, but I gather from your question you're actually iterating through a list of questions, right?  It was helpful for me in troubleshooting your issue to just write out {{questions}} in your directive's template to see the values, so I knew exactly which array index and done property I was trying to get at.

Comment: You can pass in `scope.questions[0][0]` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EZy2F/2/.  Notice I took out ngTransclude, as it wasn't necessary.  I also recommend getting away from setting `scope.height` if possible and just using CSS (you've already got `class="checkmark"`, can you not define the size there?).

Comment: Thank you for all your help!  I got it working - the main problem was actually that scope.number was a String, and it was expecting a Number!  It had nothing to do with angular at all. *facepalm*  But I never would have found it w/out your debugging help - w/out being able to confirm w/ you that my angular syntax was [mostly] right, I would've continued to assume that the bug was somewhere in there and not looked for the real problem.  I did end up needing to keep the scope: '@' to give each instance it's own scope - not sure if that's technically correct, but it works.

Comment: Re: scope.height, that has to do w/ the crazy things I'm doing throughout my app to make it scale for multiple devices - I'm scaling the width of several elements based on the height of the device (is this possible to do w/ device-height? maybe, but just setting a height variable and using it everywhere works too)